# Remover parte de string até a enésima ocorrência de um caractere

Tags: c#, .net, string

Eu tenho uma *string* que sempre retorna em algum desses formatos:

```
"0001>0002>0003>0004>0005"
"abcdef>ghi>jkl>mnopqr>stuvx"
```

Sempre tem o caractere `>` dividindo alguma coisa.

Teria como eu apagar tudo que está depois do terceiro `>`?

Por exemplo, eu tenho `"0001>0002>0003>0004>0005"` e quero só `"0001>0002>0003"`.

Ou tenho `"abcdef>ghi>jkl>mnopqr>stuvx"` e quero apenas `"abcdef>ghi>jkl"`.

Comment: Esse `string` tem sempre esse padrão, ou seja, é sempre assim do retorno ou pode variar?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A forma correta e eficiente de se fazer isto:

```
using static System.Console;
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var texto = "0001>0002>0003>0004>0005";
        var posicao = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            posicao = texto.IndexOf(">", posicao + 1);
            if (posicao == -1) break;
        }
        if (posicao > -1) texto = texto.Substring(0, posicao);
        WriteLine(texto);
        texto = "0001>0002";
        posicao = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            posicao = texto.IndexOf(">", posicao + 1);
            if (posicao == -1) break;
        }
        if (posicao > -1) texto = texto.Substring(0, posicao);
        WriteLine(texto);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/iyIP9q). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Pq6yZq). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/RemovePart.cs).

As outras formas são bastante ineficientes gerando várias alocações de memória pressionando o *garbage collector* e criando pausas na aplicação. As pessoas fazem sem pensar depois reclamam que não sabem porque a a aplicação está lenta, consumindo muita memória.

É possível ainda evitar a única alocação que é feita usando [`Span`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netcore-3.0). Não usei porque ele só pode ser usado em determinadas situações e o que o AP colocou na pergunta não é suficiente para saber se a situação dele é candidata ou não para seu uso. Se for o `Span` pode pegar a *substring* direto na *string* original sem alocação alguma, o que é o melhor dos mundos.

Comment: Quem negativou pode dizer o que tem de errado na resposta?

Comment: Também gostaria de saber, porque negativaram mas não explicaram o porquê!

Comment: @JoãoMartins eu achei um erro na minha por um lapso, e consertei, se a pessoa negativou por isso agora pode tirar o negativo, ou pode dizer onde tem mais erro que eu corrijo, eu sempre quero fazer o melhor, sempre quero ensinar o certo para as pessoas poderem programar melhor. Algumas pessoas gostam da gambiarra. Uma pessoa revertou o voto e foi justa, só podia ter comentado.

Comment: +1 sobre o "fazer sem pensar", é um dos problemas que eu vejo com frequência, as pessoas fazem o código usando a primeira função pronta que encontram na linguagem sem pensar minimamente na alocação de memória. Sua solução usa exatamente o que já tem na memória praticamente sem nenhum overhead, com zero alocação. Talvez nem o substring aloque, se o C# fizer _copy-on-write_ (não conheço os internals da função, mas acho que seja bem provável).

Comment: @JoãoMartins a sua, apesar de não muito eficiente, está correta e funciona em todas situações (que eu pude perceber), as outras respostas dão erro e ou quebram ou apresentam resultado incorreto. Uma delas teve votos demais para uma resposta errada, eu postarei em cada uma, mas algo me diz que vão considerar abusivo deizer que tem erro. Algumas pessoas reclamam que não comenta sobre o erro, outras reclamam que se comenta sobre o erro. Não tem como agradar a todos, então eu agrado quem quer o certo.

Comment: @Bacco tem só uma alocação e isto só tem um jeito de resolver com recurso novo, mas depende do que a pessoa for usar não pode ser feito. Estou colocando na resposta.

Comment: @Maniero sua solucao tem um erro no formato: https://dotnetfiddle.net/a1IJ7Z o seu formato final é `abcdef>ghi>jkl>` o solicitado é `abcdef>ghi>jkl`

Comment: @HudsonPH verdade, corrigido. Quando eu consertei o problema de pegar o final e não o começo eu tinha que ter mexido nisto e esqueci. Obrigado, ajudou ficar correto. Se você ou outra pessoa achar algo mais pode falar.

Comment: @Maniero. A lógica e a execução estão perfeitas +1, mas você reinventou a roda. O Regex faz exatamente isso que você codificou..

Comment: @AugustoVasques Só que assim faz com absurda mais eficiência geral e eu gastei menos tempo pra fazer do que eu faria com RegEx.

Comment: @Maniero. Não coloquei em questão a eficiência, tanto que dei +1. É que com Regex são duas linha de código e caso o queira modificar o padrão de busca é só alterar uma string.

Answer (score 4):

Em meio a tantas alternativas, fiz mais uma, não cheguei a validar eficiência dela em relação as outras, mas segue de toda forma:

```
string dados = "0001>0002>0003>0004>0005";
//string dados = "0001>0002>0003";

if (dados.Split('>').Length > 3)
{
    int index = dados.IndexOf('>', dados.IndexOf('>', dados.IndexOf('>') + 1) + 1);

    string antes = dados.Substring(0, index);
    string depois = dados.Substring(index + 1);
    Console.WriteLine(antes);
    Console.WriteLine(depois);
}
else
    Console.WriteLine(dados);
```

o `IndexOf`, dentro das varias sobrecargas, tem uma que é primeiro o caractere desejado e depois a partir de qual posição ele irá "validar"

Foi feita também uma validação para identificar se há ao menos 3 ocorrências do ">"

Answer (score 2):

Implemente o seguinte método para generalizar o comportamento que pretende:

```
private string DevolvePartes(string strTexto, int intPartes, string strSeparador)
{
    return string.Join(strSeparador, strTexto.Split(
        new string[] { strSeparador }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Take(intPartes));
}
```

Depois basta usar, em qualquer circunstância, da seguinte forma:

```
string strTexto = "0001>0002>0003>0004>0005";
string strTextoPartido = DevolvePartes(strTexto, 3, ">");
```

Desta forma consegue utilizar outros separadores, que não apenas ">", e separar pelas partes que entender.

Comment: Esta é uma boa solução, tentei dar uma mais 'didática' .

Comment: Gostei da lógica desse código.

Answer (score 2):

Me desculpem os contribuintes que usaram as sobrecargas do método [`String.Split`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2), ou outros artifícios, mas usar um [`Regex.Match`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Match_System_String_) é maneira mais simples e eficiente de encarar esse problema. Onde:

```
^[^>]*>([^>]*>)([^>]*)
```

é o padrão para gerar a correspondência necessária a captura.

## Código detalhado de busca do padrão:

```
// string entrada = "0001>0002>0003>0004>0005";
string entrada = "abcdef>ghi>jkl>mnopqr>stuvx";

// Cria o Regex com o seu padrão de busca
Regex reg = new Regex("^[^>]*>([^>]*>)([^>]*)"); 

// Faz a busca e guarda em correspondencia. 
Match correspondencia = reg.Match(entrada);

// se houve sucesso na busca guarda o padrão em resultado senão guarda a string "nada foi encontrado."
string resultado = (correspondencia.Success)? correspondencia.Value : "nada foi encontrado.";

//Exibe o resultado da busca.
Console.WriteLine(resultado);
```

## Mesmo código só que como uma função:

```
// Inicie o Regex dentro da classe e fora da função já que vai ser reutilizado varias vezes.
Regex reg = new Regex("^[^>]*>([^>]*>)([^>]*)");

public string Busca(string entrada) 
{
    Match correspondencia = reg.Match(entrada);
    return (correspondencia.Success) ? correspondencia.Value : "";
}
```

Comment: Talvez quem seja mais agressivo com a sintaxe do regex possa preferir o padrão `^([^>]*>){2}[^>]*` para essa mesma busca.

Comment: Tb pode usar `^([^>]+>){1,2}[^>]+`, para o caso de [ter menos que três `>`](https://regex101.com/r/172Zdz/2/) na string, e usar `+` força ter alguma coisa entre os `>` - se bem que não foi mencionado se sempre tem algo ou se pode ter `>>>`, por exemplo. Enfim, é uma solução válida, eu só questiono o "mais simples e eficiente", já que quem não está familiarizado com regex pode demorar até mais para fazer e/ou entender, e eficiente, só testando pra ver (com poucas strings não faz diferença, mas *geralmente* regex adiciona um *overhead* e dependendo do caso, nem sempre será mais eficiente)

Comment: @hkotsubo, obrigado pelo adendo.Vou levar isso em consideração no futuro,

Answer (score 1):

Com Array

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string test = "0001>0002>0003>0004>0005";

        var testSplit = test.Split('>');

        string testJoin = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            testJoin += testSplit[i] + ">";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(testJoin.Trim('>'));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Se você puder transformar em lista, fica mais fácil

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string test = "0001>0002>0003>0004>0005";

        List<string> list = new List<string>(test.Split('>'));

        list.RemoveRange(3, list.Count - 3);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(">", list));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou muito!

Comment: @EmmanuelSales feliz em poder ter ajudado :)

Comment: Há um problema com esta resposta: https://dotnetfiddle.net/N5gtEW. Seria legal arrumar isto para pelo menos justificar a aceitação.

Answer (score 1):

Como sua `string` sempre estará divida pelo caractere `>`, podemos dizer que temos um padrão, com isso, podemos dividir utilizando o método `Split()`.

```
// Aqui temos nossa string original dividida pelo caractere '>'
string padrao = "0001>0002>0003>0004>0005";
// Aqui nós dividimos em um array de strings que ficará no seguinte formato:
// "0001"
// "0002"
// "0003"
// "0004"
// "0005"
string[] padraoDividido = padrao.Split('>');
```

Agora que possuímos tudo dividido, iremos verificar se possuímos mais que 3 caracteres, casso possua iremos concatenar as `strings`:

```
string padraoFormatado = string.Empty;

if (padraoDividido.Length >= 3)
    padraoFormatado = string.Format("{0}>{1}>{2}", padraoDividido[0], padraoDividido[1], padraoDividido[2]);
```

Comment: Há um problema nesta resposta: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZVxTWU. Seria interessante arrumar para justificar tantos votos positivos.

Answer (score 1):

Mais uma solução:

```
var texto = "0001>0002>0003>0004>0005";

for (int i = texto.Length - 1, sinal = 0; i >= 0 && sinal < 2; i--)
{
    sinal += texto[i] == '>' ? 1 : 0;
    texto = texto.Substring(0, i);
}

Console.WriteLine(texto);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Esta vai retirando caracteres à string...